# How to set value to model in AngularJS using select with array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options, angularjs-select

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm trying to solve one problem in most elegant way.

I have list that comes from server and used as the source for `select` tag's `option`'s in my application. Lets assume that it's a list of authors which looks like this:

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'Mark Twain' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Jack London' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Ernest Hemingway' }
]
```

Also I have **book** model which comes from and saved to server. One of book's properties is `author` which can be choosen by user from `select` dropdown. When **book** model is saved or fetched from server it's `author` field is represented as integer. Here is an example of how **book** model should be saved on server and how it looks when fetched:

```
{
  id: 324,
  title: 'Martin Eden',
  author: 2
}
```

**book** is represented as Angular's `$resource` in my application so whenever I want to save book model I just call it's save method.

To implement this logic I have tried to use `select` with `ng-options` directive, like this:

```
<select ng-options="author as author.name for author in authors track by author.id" ng-model="bookModel.author"></select>
```

But the problem with this approach is that when I pick author from drop down the value of `author` property is set to `{ id: 2, name: 'Jack London' }` but I need it to be an author's id.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cake_Seller/55zevgjr/2/) that illustrates my problem. Try to select different values in drop down. Below the drop down you will see updated value of `bookModel.author`. I need it to be an author's id integer, not the object. So whenever I choose *Jack London* in drop down I need the value of `bookModel.author` to be `2`, not `{ id: 2, name: 'Jack London' }`. Otherwise I need do manipulations with data whenever **book** model comes from server and before I save it. I suppose that there can be a better way. Maybe it is something that can be achieved with `ng-options` directive?

I have tried do it this way:

```
<select ng-model="bookModel.author">
  <option ng-repeat="author in authors" value="{{author.id}}">{{author.name}}</option>
</select>
```

It's a bit closer but this way `bookModel.author`'s value will be a string, not integer.

Also I know that I can set `transformRequest` and `transformResponse` functions for book $resource which will transform data to appropriate format. But maybe there is a better way?

Will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `author.id as author.name` on your `ng-options` like so:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="testController">
    <select ng-options="author.id as author.name for author in authors track by author.id" ng-model="bookModel.author"></select>
    <pre>{{bookModel.author | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, if you want the author's name:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="testController">
    <select ng-options="author.name as author.name for author in authors track by author.id" ng-model="bookModel.author"></select>
    <pre>{{bookModel.author | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 1**

Updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/55zevgjr/3/)

Comment: That works perfect when I select author from drop down. But what if `author` property already has value? I thought in that case it should be displayed as selected in drop down, but it's not. Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cake_Seller/55zevgjr/4/). As you can see select doesn't have any option selected.

Comment: Other guy helped me resolve this final issue. All I needed is to remove `track by author.id` part from ng-options directive. Here is final [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cake_Seller/55zevgjr/7/).
Thanks a lot for your help!